# How to check whether the file is a raster or not?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Is there a function for getting the logical value of either `TRUE` or `FALSE` whether a certain file, for example `/path/to/raster.hdr` is a raster file?

Probably something like:

```
raster.test <- is.raster("/path/to/raster.hdr")
```

I know there is a function `spatial.tools::is.Raster()` for this but [it seems already been dropped/archived](https://cran.r-project.org/package=spatial.tools).

**How to check whether the file is a raster or not?**

Comment: I note that `spatial.tools::is.Raster()` is [on github](https://github.com/cran/spatial.tools/blob/master/R/is.Raster.R). But it seems to check if an _R object_ is a raster, whereas you want to check a _file_, so it may not help you...

Answer (score 2):

You could try loading it as a raster and see if an error is generated

```
tryCatch({raster("/path/to/raster.hdr"); TRUE}, error = function(e) FALSE)
```